# Firebreath plugin crashing due to opening of multiple tabs

Tags: javascript, tabs, safari, firebreath

During testing phase of my plugin, I had loaded the firebreath demo plugin on multiple tabs of Safari.. But when tabs goes above 15 ,unfortunately the browser crashed, The other browser works fine..Why so?

I am working on Windows 7(32-bit) . This error is encountered only on Safari. This error is never encountered when i attach the debugger.The following is the attached screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Not a clue.  Let us know if you figure it out.

Comment: Did you get any debug information? You are working with Safari on Mac or Windows?

Comment: Safari on Windows. Sorry for a very late reply @WayneWang